# Filter DataFrame by regex and match condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following DataFrame:

| Periodicity | Answer |
| --- | --- |
| M | Yes |
| M | YeS |
| Y | yeS |
| M | No |
| Y | NO |
| M | nO |

I need to filter the DataFrame to get the rows that have a Monthly (M) periodicity and have a positive (YES, YEs, Yes, YeS, and so on) answer.

I have tried filter it with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

data = {'Periodicity': ['M', 'Y', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'Y', 'M', 'M'],
        'Answer': ['YES', 'Yes', 'YEs', 'NO', 'no', 'No', 'yeS', 'yeS']}
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pat=r'^[Yy].*'

df_filter=df[df.Answer.str.contains(pat)]
```

But I dont know how to add another condition to filter the DataFrame to match the desired Periodicity. Everytime I add another filter condition, I get the following error message:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all`().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_filter=df[df.Answer.str.contains(pat) & df.Periodicity.str.contains('M')]
```

Comment: Thank you ! :)

I also found that when you work with pandas, you should use "bitwise" | (or) or & (and) operations.

The conditions should be contained between parentesys .

So I also solve the problem using this code:

df_filter=df[(df.Answer.str.contains(pat)) & (df.Periodicity=='M')]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without regex (by using string `lower` method and dataframe filtering :

```
import pandas as pd
import re

data = {'Periodicity': ['M', 'Y', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'Y', 'M', 'M'],
        'Answer': ['YES', 'Yes', 'YEs', 'NO', 'no', 'No', 'yeS', 'yeS']}
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df[(df['Answer'].str.lower() == 'yes') & (df['Periodicity'] == 'M')] # do this

print(df)
```

output:

```
  Periodicity Answer
0           M    YES
2           M    YEs
6           M    yeS
7           M    yeS
```

Comment: I must use regex for this exercise.

Your answer also works and gets the same result.

Thank you :).